# Why does mongodb $all operator use all subarrays for quering?

Tags: mongodb

I have some test documents that are structured as follows:

```
{
        "foo" : {
                "bar" : [
                        {
                                "a" : [
                                        "1",
                                        "4"
                                ]
                        },
                        {
                                "a" : [
                                        "1",
                                        "7"
                                ]
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Now I try to get all these documents where at least one of the "a" arrays contains the strings "1","4" and "7". (Note: I know that this example document should not be found!)

Now I query the db like this:

```
db.test.find({"foo.bar.a": {$all: ["1","4","7"]}})
```

In my opinion it should tell me that no document is found, but it finds the example document, as "1" and "4" are contained in the first "a" array and "7" is contained in the second "a" array.

Is this a bug of the $all operator, or is my query just wrong?

Comment: It is because of the path you are using `foo.bar.a` it will match all `a` fields in `bar`. If you wanna limit it specifically you need to use a numerical index like: `foo.bar.0.a`

Comment: @Sammaye the problem is I do not espacially want to query only the first array. Also I do not know how many arrays there will be. Is there a way to tell it that all numbers must be contained in one of those arrays?

Comment: I must admit I cannot think of a way off of the top of my head, edit: you could do an elemMatch here

Comment: Yea I tested it with $elemMatch and it kind works, the problem is that it requires an order to the values, so where `db.gf.find({"foo.bar":{$elemMatch:{"a": ["1","4"]}}})` works `db.gf.find({"foo.bar":{$elemMatch:{"a": ["4","1"]}}})` does not also it evals the object itself so you must provide an entire `a`. But if you ensured the order of your values, maybe ASC numeric order, this could work

Comment: awsome! if you post this as an awnswer I will accept it. this is what I was trying to do! edit: What do you mean with, "you must provide an entire `a`"

Comment: I didn't see this before until after I posted the comment initially but elemMatch evaluates the expression `a` which means if you have 4,5,7 and search by 4,5 it won't work.

Comment: Oh I see, haven checked that yet. Thanks for explaining it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2+ to `$unwind` the `foo.bar.a` array into a stream of documents that will match as expected.

Example query:

```
db.test.aggregate(
    // Could add a $match here to limit the number of relevant documents

    // Create a stream of documents from the foo.bar array
    { $unwind: '$foo.bar' },

    // Find arrays that have the desired elements
    { $match: {
        'foo.bar.a': { $all: ["1","4","7"] }
    }},

    // Re-group by original document _id with matching array elements
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        'a': { $push: '$foo.bar.a' }
    }}
)
```

Sample result:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("50f08b392aa92c6de18aa70a"),
            "a" : [
                [
                    "7",
                    "4",
                    "1"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("50f08b322aa92c6de18aa709"),
            "a" : [
                [
                    "1",
                    "4",
                    "7"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? One element whose "a" array contains all specified values.

db.test.find({"foo.bar": {$elemMatch: {"a": {$all: ["1", "4", "7"]}}}})